# Spring Data Load All lazy initialized Child Tables from Parent

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent Entity with 2 child entities that are lazily loaded. I would like to load all the associated child entities when the parent entity is loaded

```
@Entity
public class Author {
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="author",cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Post> posts;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="author",cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Book> books;
 }
```

Load all Books and Posts based on the Author firstname by using Dynamic query.

```
    public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
       public  List<Author>findByFirstNameAndPostsAndBooks()
    }
```

The Above Findby does not work, please assist me to construct the correct Query.
Also i am trying to avoid @Query or QueryDSL for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch authors by their firstname you should change you query to this:

```
public List<Author>findByFirstName(String firstname);
```

`JPA` will load the authors `posts` and `books` automatically because of your `@OneToMany` annotations in your `Author` class.

Add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=tr‌​ue` to your `application.properties` file to enable lazy loading without transactional annotations.

Comment: Even FetchType Lazy will work when i have my Query as  findByPostsTitle on my CRUD Repository as the child table has a where clause of title. My Problem is i would like to load all posts and books by the author firstname without specifying any where clause on the child table using the Spring Data Dynamic Query

Comment: @onlinecarren you mean something like this? `public List<Author>findByFirstName(String firstname);` This will get all authors by name and jpa provides all the posts and books of him because of your `@OneToMany` annotation.

Comment: but i would like to stick to the lazy initialization as i do not want to load by child tables unless i need to for performance reasons

Comment: @onlinecarren no problem. Just leave it by lazy. JPA will load it if you use a getter. But is this query working for you? I will update my answer then.

Comment: No the query findByFirstNameAndPostsAndBooks does not work for me, as a matter of fact when i start the springboot it throws an Exception for  saying this is not parsable

Comment: @onlinecarren. You have to use this query to find authors by firstname: `public List<Author>findByFirstName(String firstname);` Jpa do the rest for you.

Comment: when i access  a getPosts on the author object from my service class i get a lazyintialization exception in which case  i have to put my service method  in a @transnational scope resulting in an additional DB hit to load the Child Table

Comment: @onlinecarren you can put this property to your ´application.properties´ file to enable lazy loading without using transaction `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`

Comment: Patrick coming back to the same point this is same as Eager fetching , it wil load the child even when not required, my point is it possible using Spring Data JPA query to load the child without a where clause without Eager fetching using a method like this findByFirstNameAndPostsAndBooks

Comment: sorry @onlinecarren if you have lazy loading in your OneToMany mapping it will only loaded if you need it. So there is no eager fetching if you say lazy.

Comment: Patrick findByFirstNameAndPosts on my repository does not work, can you help me construct the Correct Spring Data JPA Method, first name is my author entity and i just want it to join with posts without a where clause in the posts entity

Comment: @onlinecarren I provided the correct method in my answer and in the comments. It will fetch authors by firstname lazy loaded. your method name `findByFirstNameAndPosts` is still wrong.

Comment: i know findByFirstNameAndPosts  is wrong, are you referring to the method findByFirstName you suggested, as i said this does not return the lazy collection in which case i need to perform an eager fetch or use  enable_lazy_load_no_trans that can lead to performance problems , the second way to do it load it within a @Transactional scope which will fire the query when accessing the child List which is an additional DB Hit which is not desirable

Comment: @onlinecarren sorry, I really dont understand your problem now. please update your question with all your issues and what you want as solution.